# Hibernate generates one ID for two tables/entities

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

In my SpringBoot Project (Java 11), I have a "user" and a "product" table. One user can have multiple products, one product can only have one user/owner. So I used a @OneToMany and @ManyToOne annotations and linked the two tables with the user_id:

**My problem:** The id seems to not count individually for each table, but seems to count both tables together. When I save a user it gets ID = 1. When I save a product it then gets ID = 2. But of course I want the product ID to count independently from the user ID.

[image: user]

[image: product]

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})  
private List<Product> products;



@Entity
public class Product {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;
```

I also tried generation strategiy TABLE, but that didn't seem to change anything.

```
2020-06-24 09:00:46.492  INFO 11636 --- [  restartedMain]     
c.e.studileih.StudileihApplication       : Starting StudileihApplication on    
2020-06-24 09:00:46.496  INFO 11636 --- [  restartedMain] 
c.e.studileih.StudileihApplication       : No active profile set, falling   
back to default profiles: default
2020-06-24 09:00:46.564  INFO 11636 --- [  restartedMain] 
.e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active!   
Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2020-06-24 09:00:46.565  INFO 11636 --- [  restartedMain] 
.e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging    
consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2020-06-24 09:00:47.416  INFO 11636 --- [  restartedMain] 
.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA 
repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-06-24 09:00:47.503  INFO 11636 --- [  restartedMain] 
.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository   
scanning in 76ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-06-24 09:00:48.529  INFO 11636 --- [  restartedMain] 
o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s):   
8090 (http)
2020-06-24 09:00:48.542  INFO 11636 --- [  restartedMain] 
o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-06-24 09:00:48.542  INFO 11636 --- [  restartedMain] 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache  
Tomcat/9.0.34]
2020-06-24 09:00:48.651  INFO 11636 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].
[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-06-24 09:00:48.651  INFO 11636 --- [  restartedMain] 
o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: 
initialization completed in 2086 ms
2020-06-24 09:00:48.835  INFO 11636 --- [  restartedMain] 
o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing 
PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-06-24 09:00:48.880  INFO 11636 --- [  restartedMain] 
org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core 
version 5.4.15.Final
2020-06-24 09:00:49.006  INFO 11636 --- [  restartedMain] 
o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons 
Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-06-24 09:00:49.109  INFO 11636 --- [  restartedMain] 
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-06-24 09:00:49.176  INFO 11636 --- [  restartedMain] 
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-06-24 09:00:49.194  INFO 11636 --- [  restartedMain] 
org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: 
org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB53Dialect
2020-06-24 09:00:49.270  WARN 11636 --- [  restartedMain] 
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder       : HHH000503: A class should not be 
annotated with both @Inheritance and @MappedSuperclass. @Inheritance will be 
ignored for: com.example.studileih.Entity.BaseEntity.
Hibernate: create table `product` (`id` bigint not null, `available` bit not 
null, `created_at` datetime(6), `name` varchar(255), `pic_paths` tinyblob, 
`price` double precision not null, `title` varchar(255), `type` varchar(255), 
`updated_at` datetime(6), `views` integer not null, `user_id` bigint, primary 
key (`id`)) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: create table `hibernate_sequence` (`next_val` bigint) 
engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: insert into `hibernate_sequence` values ( 1 )
Hibernate: insert into `hibernate_sequence` values ( 1 )
Hibernate: create table `user` (`id` bigint not null, `city` varchar(255), 
`created_at` datetime(6), `dorm` varchar(255), `email` varchar(255), `name` 
varchar(255), `password` varchar(255), `profile_pic` varchar(255), `room` 
varchar(255), `updated_at` datetime(6), primary key (`id`)) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: alter table `product` add constraint `FKlmddkhx1lun30vpyotj9427rj` 
foreign key (`user_id`) references `user` (`id`)
2020-06-24 09:00:50.034  INFO 11636 --- [  restartedMain] 
o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform 
implementation:   
[org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-06-24 09:00:50.040  INFO 11636 --- [  restartedMain] 
j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA   
EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-06-24 09:00:50.052  INFO 11636 --- [  restartedMain] 
o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on 
port 35729


Hibernate: select `next_val` as id_val from `hibernate_sequence` for update
Hibernate: update `hibernate_sequence` set `next_val`= ? where `next_val`=?
Hibernate: select `next_val` as id_val from `hibernate_sequence` for update
Hibernate: update `hibernate_sequence` set `next_val`= ? where `next_val`=?
Hibernate: insert into `user` (`city`, `created_at`, `dorm`, `email`, `name`, 
`password`, `profile_pic`, `room`, `updated_at`, `id`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into `product` (`available`, `created_at`, `name`, 
`pic_paths`, `price`, `title`, `type`, `updated_at`, `user_id`, `views`, 
`id`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select product0_.`id` as id1_0_0_, product0_.`available` as 
availabl2_0_0_, product0_.`created_at` as created_3_0_0_, product0_.`name` as 
name4_0_0_, product0_.`pic_paths` as pic_path5_0_0_, product0_.`price` as 
price6_0_0_, product0_.`title` as title7_0_0_, product0_.`type` as 
type8_0_0_, product0_.`updated_at` as updated_9_0_0_, product0_.`user_id` as 
user_id11_0_0_, product0_.`views` as views10_0_0_ from `product` product0_ 
where product0_.`id`=?
Hibernate: update `product` set `available`=?, `name`=?, `pic_paths`=?, 
`price`=?, `title`=?, `type`=?, `updated_at`=?, `user_id`=?, `views`=? where  
`id`=?


2020-06-24 09:00:50.604  WARN 11636 --- [  restartedMain] 
JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled 
by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view 
rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this 
warning
2020-06-24 09:00:50.760  INFO 11636 --- [  restartedMain] 
o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 
'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-06-24 09:00:50.977  INFO 11636 --- [  restartedMain] 
o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8090 
(http) with context path ''
2020-06-24 09:00:50.981  INFO 11636 --- [  restartedMain] 
c.e.studileih.StudileihApplication       : Started StudileihApplication in   
4.886 seconds (JVM running for 5.556)
```

Comment: Could you please show the ddl sql of your tables. What database do you use?

Comment: I'm using MariaDB and I added the ddl sql output in my question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with code below

```java
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name="user_generator", sequenceName = "user_seq", allocationSize=50)
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "product_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name="product_generator", sequenceName = "product_seq", allocationSize=50)
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
```

Comment: It seems to work,thanks, but one question: Why allocationSize=50? I just read that it's the default value, but then my IDs go: 1, 52, 103... why would anyone want that, what's the reason?

Comment: I changed it now to allocationSize=1 and now the ID is counting normally 1, 2, 3 ...

Comment: allocationSize=50 is good action if you need insert with many row in onetime, hibernate will keep index id and dont need query db to get new index until you insert more 50 objects
e.g:
you set allocationSize is 1 and you save a list with 10 object hibernate wil get the latest index from your db and set for object but you set allocationSize is 10 so hibernate just query first time to get index and auto update the latest index for each object, if you set allocationSize is 10 and you save a list with 20 objects hibernate wil query two time

Comment: When setting the allocationSize to 50 you'd also want to modify your sequence to incrementBy 50. When you stop the application, unused "allocated" Ids per sequence are "lost" and show up as gaps though. The upside is, as Van Dung Nguyen explained, that it might speed up insertion time a bit.