# common id for two tables one to many

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have two tables with one2many relationship. For some reason, records from the second table continue the ID numbering after the first, and do not start over.

```
@Entity
public class Result {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String date;
    private String bank;
    private Integer baseCurrency;
    private String baseCurrencyLit;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "result", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    //@OrderColumn(name = "array_index")
    //private ExchangeRate[] exchangeRate;
    private List<ExchangeRate> exchangeRate;
```

```
@Entity
public class ExchangeRate {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String baseCurrency;
    private String currency;
    private Float saleRateNB;
    private Float purchaseRateNB;
    private Float saleRate;
    private Float purchaseRate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name= "result_id")
    private Result result;
```

Result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNxER.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTwz0.png)

Comment: here is answer on your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62548985/hibernate-generates-one-id-for-two-tables-entities

Comment: The question is a duplicate, but the linked one really doesn't answer it - the reason is because you haven't specified the sequence to use, so they both default to using the same sequence generator. By defining different generators, each can use their own independent series of sequences.